# Take daily snapshot of table in Postgresql and append it to another table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a table in Postgresql which stores product information and it's price. The problem is, as price of the product changes, the prices are updated in existing rows, so I do not have the historical data. I would like to take a snapshot of this table every night at 12:00 and store this data in another table so that I can find out change in price everyday.

The postgresql database is hosted in AWS. I have to write a node.js script which does this task. You can assume the Table structure to be like:

| Product | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Prod_1 | 20 |
| Prod_2 | 25 |

The result should be:

| Produce | Price | Snapshot at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Prod_1 | 20 | 2021-01-22 |
| Prod_2 | 25 | 2021-01-22 |
| Prod_1 | 22 | 2021-01-23 |
| Prod_2 | 21 | 2021-01-23 |

Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you facing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'd suggest using an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger on the `price` field. Write to an audit table with the `OLD` record when you update the price.

Comment: Hi everyone,
I am using 'pg' package in Node js. I can successfully print the rows in a table which is stored in PostgreSQL in an AWS environment.
What I'd like to achieve is to extend this script and store the results of the query in my local machine everyday.
I have PostgreSQL in my local machine